# (Swift) Elegant way of writing this sort?

Tags: swift, sorting

Let's say I have this struct:

```
struct TestStruct {
    enum Category {
        case a
        case b
        case c
        var sortIndex: Int {
            switch self {
            case .a:
                return 1
            case .b:
                return 0
            case .c:
                return 2
            }
        }
    }
    var category: Category
    var name: String
}
```

I want to order a collection containing these by their category's sortIndex. Here is what I did :

```
let tableTest: [TestStruct] = [TestStruct(category: .b, name: "hello"),
                               TestStruct(category: .c, name: "hi"),
                               TestStruct(category: .a, name: "ok"),
                               TestStruct(category: .b, name: "bye")]

print(tableTest.sorted(by: { (first, second) -> Bool in
    first.category.sortIndex < second.category.sortIndex
}))
```

> hello, bye, ok, hi

It works but I want to know if there is a more elegant and fast way of writing this.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do something like this:

```
extension TestStruct.Category: Comparable {
    static func < (lhs: TestStruct.Category, rhs: TestStruct.Category) -> Bool {
        return lhs.sortIndex < rhs.sortIndex
    }
}

extension TestStruct: Comparable {
    static func < (lhs: TestStruct, rhs: TestStruct) -> Bool {
        return lhs.category < rhs.category
    }
}
```

and then

```
print(tableTest.sorted())
```

---

**N.B.**: `TestStruct` may require you to define method (`static func == (::) -> Bool`) of `Equatable` which you can write by yourself, or autoimplement it by adding conformance to `Equatable` in struct declaration:

```
struct TestStruct: Equatable {
    //  …
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use like this

```
tableTest.sorted(by: { $0.category.sortIndex < $1.category.sortIndex })
```